# Multi modal learning from separate modal datasets

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks

Let's say I'm trying to learn emotion given multi-modal sources. In this case, video and audio. However, I only have one dataset for video emotions and one dataset for audio. Is it possible to train a Deep Learning classifier on each dataset separately? One way I can imagine doing this is creating some sort of shared hidden units, similar to the figure below:
[image]

However, [in the publication this is taken from](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Wang_MMSS_Multi-Modal_Sharable_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf), these weights are trained simultaneously.

Are there examples of this type of multi-modal learning in the literature? I'm not sure what to look up and all I can come up with myself is "something-something Deep Belief Network".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 2012, this was accomplished by Srivastava and Salakhutdinov in "[Learning Representations for Multimodal Data with Deep Belief
Nets](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~nitish/icml2012/paper.pdf)" where they mixed textual and visual features using the following Deep Belief network architecture:

[image: multi-modal DBN]

Note the specially defined hidden layer that can be trained independently.

More recently in 2015, this was accomplished by Huang, Y.; Wang, W. and Wang, L. in "[Unconstrained Multimodal Multi-Label Learning](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~nitish/icml2012/paper.pdf)" where they use a conditional Restricted Boltzmann Machine applied to creating text labels for images:

[image: conditional restricted boltzmann machine]

Note that each observed variable, `t` for tags and `m` for images are connected to `h`, but there is the built in assumption that `m` is more frequently available than `t`.

One problem with both of these approaches is I'm unclear on how well they're going to scale.